# Can I change the default search behavior in Brave?

Tags: search, address-bar, omnibox, brave

I've noticed a change in the way that Brave handles non-URL text typed into its version of the omnibox. I'm not sure whether this is a change in the way Google search results are presented in this context, or if this is just a change in the way Brave handles them. For all I know, I've unknowingly changed a setting on my end that just happened to coincide with my recent browser update to Brave Version 1.5.123 Chromium: 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Before, if I typed "you" into the address bar and hit enter, the browser would automatically navigate to www.youtube.com.

Since the update, typing "you" into the address bar and hitting enter brings me to Google's search results page, with YouTube as the top result.

I've tried bookmarking YouTube and renaming the bookmark "you" in order to circumvent this new behavior, but this doesn't seem to work either. Is there some way to change Brave's settings such that this works the way I'm accustomed to, or is there an extension I can install to accomplish the same thing?